# Is there any way I can control the line style of the outer circle and the base station separately?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to have a dashed circle with the base-station normally in block, un-dashed.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{naming/.style={align=center,font=\small}}
\tikzset{antenna/.style={insert path={-- coordinate (ant#1) ++(0,0.25) -- +(135:0.25) + (0,0) -- +(45:0.25)}}}
\tikzset{station/.style={naming,draw,shape=dart,shape border rotate=90, minimum width=1mm, minimum height=1mm,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=1mm}}
\tikzset{radiation/.style={{decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=90,segment length=4pt}}}}


\newcommand{\BS}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[station] (base) {#1};

\draw[line join=bevel] (base.100) -- (base.80) -- (base.110) -- (base.70) -- (base.north west) -- (base.north east);
\draw[line join=bevel] (base.100) -- (base.70) (base.110) -- (base.north east);

\draw[line cap=rect] ([yshift=0pt]base.north) [antenna=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, shape = circle, minimum size=1cm] at (0,2) {\BS{\tiny SBS}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `solid` for the `station` style of the antenna and the drawings of the `\BS` command.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{naming/.style={align=center,font=\small}}
\tikzset{antenna/.style={insert path={-- coordinate (ant#1) ++(0,0.25) -- +(135:0.25) + (0,0) -- +(45:0.25)}}}
\tikzset{station/.style={solid,naming,draw,shape=dart,shape border rotate=90, minimum width=1mm, minimum height=1mm,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=1mm}}
\tikzset{radiation/.style={{decorate,decoration={expanding waves,angle=90,segment length=4pt}}}}

\newcommand{\BS}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[station] (base) {#1};

    \draw[solid,line join=bevel] (base.100) -- (base.80) -- (base.110) -- (base.70) -- (base.north west) -- (base.north east);
    \draw[solid,line join=bevel] (base.100) -- (base.70) (base.110) -- (base.north east);

    \draw[solid,line cap=rect] ([yshift=0pt]base.north) [antenna=1];
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw, shape = circle, minimum size=1cm,dashed] at (0,2) {\BS{\tiny SBS}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]